# Image blur on hover

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to blur a 3 images, whose are inside a flexbox separately, but after many tries I've ran out of ideas how to do it. I've tried to do hover on almost every single combination of divs eg. .categories .row1 .column1. img:hover using filter:blur(). Anything of those didn't work.

Here's html code:

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="column1">
            <img src="imgs/main-page/1.jpg" alt="Sesje zdjęciowe" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="column2">
            <img src="imgs/main-page/2.jpg" alt="Imprezy okolicznościowe" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
        <div class="column3">
            <img src="imgs/main-page/3.jpg" alt="Klienci firmowi" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's a CSS styling:

```
.categories {
   display: flex;
   height: 92vh;
}

.row1,
.row2,
.row3 {
   display: flex;
   height: 92vh;
   flex: 33.33%;
}

.column1 {
   flex: 33.33%;
   padding: 0px 3px 0px 0px;
}

.column2 {
   flex: 33.33%;
   padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
}

.column3 {
   flex: 33.33%;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;

}

.column1 img,
.column2 img,
.column3 img {
   height: 92vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` property and `blur()` function to create the blur effect.

```css
.categories {
  display: flex;
  height: 92vh;
}

.row1,
.row2,
.row3 {
  display: flex;
  height: 92vh;
  flex: 33.33%;
}

.column1 {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px 3px 0px 0px;
}

.column2 {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
}

.column3 {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;

}

.column1 img,
.column2 img,
.column3 img {
  height: 92vh;
}

img:hover {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="column1">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/901/300/300.jpg?hmac=8-Zxyl2URaVHsQFbRJNKJ52yofy7UGOXSOPAa_bepfs" alt="Sesje zdjęciowe" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="column2">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/914/300/300.jpg?hmac=ghkx68JWW6IEeaozmhAeyojhquNUUoGhH1ULrp0DwpE" alt="Imprezy okolicznościowe" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div class="column3">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/256/300/300.jpg?hmac=NY-Kc_0T-LRop_egfEehw6sHGvf-vHsyL6CBFUJyaWQ" alt="Klienci firmowi" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Reference: [filter CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: I didn't precise a question. I've been trying to blur it using filter:blur, but it didn't work. img:hover only works on my logo, not a actual photos inside "categories" container.